# Testing with a metaoperator doesn't print the test description

Tags: testing, raku

I was writing tests on Complex arrays and I was using the `Z≅` operator to check whether the arrays were approximately equal, when I noticed a missing test description.
I tried to golf the piece of code to find out the simplest case that shows the result I was seeing. The description is missing in the second test even when I use Num or Int variables and the `Z==` operator.

```
use Test;

my @a = 1e0, 3e0;
my @b = 1e0, 3e0;
ok @a[0] == @b[0], 'description1';     # prints: ok 1 - description1
ok @a[^2] Z== @b[^2], 'description2';  # prints: ok 2 -

done-testing;
```

Is there a simple explanation or is this a bug?

Comment: Please note that the test: `ok @a[^2] Z== @b[^2]` is bogus, as it will **always** be ok.  Because you're really testing the number of elements in the result, which is always a `Seq` that produces 2 values.  You would need to check if all values of the `Seq` are `True`, e.g. by doing `ok [&&] @a[^2] Z== @b[^2]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just precedence -- you need parens.

`==` is a binary op that takes *a single operand* on either side.

The `Z` metaop distributes its operator to *a list* on either side.

```
use Test;

my @a = 1e0, 3e0;
my @b = 1e0, 3e0;
ok  @a[0]   == @b[0],   'description1';  # prints: ok 1 - description1
ok (@a[^2] Z== @b[^2]), 'description2';  # prints: ok 2 - description2

done-testing;
```

Without parens, `'description2'` becomes an additional element of the list on the right. And per [the doc for `Z`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/Z):

> If one of the operands runs out of elements prematurely, the zip operator will stop.